# How do normal modes have group velocity?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, phonons

Considering phonon dispersion curves in crystals, the group velocity is given by the derivative of frequency with respect to wave vector.

But these modes on the dispersion represent **normal modes**, which don't propagate like waves because they are standing.

So why do we say that these modes can have group velocity and travel like waves?

Comment: Hmm ... are you aware that standing waves arise when you have counter-propagating traveling waves?

Comment: @dmckee yes, so does group velocity refer to the counter-propagating waves? Because they surely can't refer to the modes themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure that it makes much sense to try to draw a distinction there. The dispersion relationship tells you how $k$ and $\omega$ are related and the standing waves continue to have those properties so you still need to know the relationship between them. Maybe the "velocity" nomenclature is a little weird when applied to the standing waves, but it is still a useful quantity.

Comment: @dmckee Why is it useful? The only thing I can think of is calculating thermal conductivity using the kinetic model for phonons.

Comment: Keep in mind that standing waves are not just a solid-state phenomena. Consider that if the wavelength is constrained (as in a plucked string or your phonos) then the nature of the (frequency) spectrum is determined by the dispersion relation (harmonic for non-dispersive waves, but different if there is non-trivial dispersion). This has potential applications in any couple vibrations system.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the standing wave is the superposition of two waves, one going forward and one going backward. The velocity of these waves directly influences how the normal mode behave (in fact, they are determined by the velocity of oscillation of our normal mode); when you talk about the wave velocity, this is the "physical" velocity from both propagating waves that interferes to create the standing one.

Answer (score 1):

Standing waves (normal modes) are mathematically equivalent to two moving waves of equal amplitude and frequency travelling in opposite directions.

When you have a sum of two pure, travelling sine waves, you get *beats* - such that the total wave looks like a sine wave of different frequency modulated by an *envelope*. Group velocity is the velocity of the envelope, while phase velocity is the velocity of the individual peaks.

Namely, if you have waves

$$w_1(x, t) := A_1 \cos(k_1 x + \omega_1 t + \phi_1)\ \ \ \mathrm{and}\ \ \ w_2(x, t) := A_2 \cos(k_2 x + \omega_2 t + \phi_2)$$

then the envelope of the *total wave*

$$w_\mathrm{tot}(x, t) := w_1(x, t) + w_2(x, t)$$

travels with the group speed

$$v_g := \frac{\omega_1 - \omega_2}{k_1 + k_2}$$

where $\omega$ and $k$ are respectively the angular frequency and angular wave number (angular spatial frequency).

The trick is this: If we set $\omega_1 := (-\omega_2 := \omega)$, $k_1 := k_2 := k$, and $A_1 := A_2 := A$,. then the total wave $w_\mathrm{tot}$ will be a standing wave: the conditions here amount to two superposed waves of exactly the same amplitude, same temporal and same spatial frequencies but traveling contrary to each other (negating either $\omega$ *xor* $k$ will work). Conversely, any standing wave can be so written. With these assignments $v_g$ gives, for this situation, that

$$v_g = \frac{(\omega) - (-\omega)}{k + k} = \frac{2\omega}{2k} = \frac{\omega}{k}$$

which is not zero for anything we typically think of as a "wave". Note that this velocity is also identical to the wave speed: the "envelope" moves at the same speed as the waves themselves. Moreover, the *phase velocity* - or velocity of the peaks - is zero:

$$v_p := \frac{\omega_1 + \omega_2}{k_1 + k_2} = \frac{\omega + (-\omega)}{k + k} = 0$$

which again, makes sense since the peaks stand still, which is the whole point of calling it a "standing wave".

Answer (score 0):

What you're saying is correct, **normal modes don't propagate**. Phonons, on the other hand, do not consist purely out of one mode but are the sum of many normal modes of the lattice. That **wave packet** though can propagate and has a collective velocity (called group velocity). The wiki article explains most of the important points about wave packets.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet

If you want to know more you can search most classical physics books (e.g. Goldstein) which will probably have a section devoted to wave mechanics.